# How do you get a long lived access token with the javascript sdk?

Tags: oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

This article introduces the new endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token

But since I'm using the javascript sdk, I obviously don't want to put the client_secret into my javascript. I am going to implement this with a proxy page on my server, but I would prefer a user-agent type of flow or better yet a javascript sdk function.

The main reason I want this feature is that I still want people using my site to be able to push stuff to their facebook accounts event if they've logged out or switched accounts which I can't do with the current access tokens.

Who has info about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you need to pass the token to your server-side code and do the code exchange there.

Do **not** put your app secret in client code, it allows complete takeover of your app

There probably should be no need to do a code exchange for a javascript app anyways, as the user will still be in your app, and you'll get an updated short-lived token when they refresh the page or leave and come back